# Remove default shadow on iOS view components

Tags: android, ios, css, react-native, shadow

I notice that iOS is setting a default shadow in its views in my app that i'm building using react native.
While on the android version it is rendering correctly without any shadows, on iOS, even if I set all the shadow styles with value of 0 and transparent, it still shows a subtle shadow, as you can see in the images below

On Android you can see a View with the same color os the background image, no shadow is seen:

[image: On Android you can see a View with the same color os the background image, no shadow is seen:]

On iOS you can clearly see the shadow around the view, even if I set all shadow styles with 0 value

[image: On iOS you can clearly see the shadow around the view, even if I set all shadow styles with 0 value]

And here is the style applied to the view:

```
height: 50, 
backgroundColor: Colors.background
shadowColor: 'transparent',
shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 0 },
shadowOpacity: 0,
shadowRadius: 0,
elevation: 0
```

Any idea in how i can remove this default shadows on iOS?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you share style of view about shadow?

Comment: Sure, I added it to the question

Comment: Your shared style must work. Are you sure give that style to right view? Because this is absolutely hide your shadow. You can check from toggle inspector.

Comment: Yes... for me it still appears the shadow.

Comment: Probably you can find easily shadowed style View in your code. But if you dont, you can share as a snack.expo. So we can solve. Good luck  :)